# Limit text file to one sentence OR a maximum amount of words

Tags: vb.net, string, text-files, line, limit

Hi I have a program I am working on in VB.NET that opens a text file and reads a text file and limits the number of words per line to whatever the user sets and then capitalizes the first letter of each line.

This is the code I have that does that and it works; however, I would like to take it a step further and have it jump to a new line if it detects a punctuation mark like a period or exclamation mark, **OR** if it doesn't detect any punctuation for a while limit it to X amount of words per line like it is already doing.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
'Limit line to X amount of words

Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
Dim textLine As String
Dim count As Integer = MAIN_FORM.wordCountBox.Value
Dim pos As Integer = 0

Do While reader.Peek <> -1

    textLine = reader.ReadLine

    'Split the line to the individual words
    Dim parts = textLine.Split(" "c)
    Do
        'Skip the previous words and take the count required
        Dim block = parts.Skip(pos).Take(count).ToArray

        'position to read the next count words
        pos += count

        If block.Count > 0 Then
            block(0) = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(block(0))
        End If

        MAIN_FORM.previewBox.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", block))

    Loop While (pos < parts.Length)

Loop
```

For example if I had it set to limit each line to 7 words I would like it to only have 7 words on each line, but if I had a particular line that was like this "Three word sentence." Even though that is only 3 words which is less than the limit of 7 I would like it to just stop there since that is a complete sentence.

FYI Previewbox is a regular listbox control.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a picture explaining the output I am getting.

[image]

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I just want to get it to limit each line to **ONE** sentence **OR** X amount of words. I have it limiting each line to X amount of words, but I would like it to stop each line if it detects a period.

Comment: Please describe the word "Limit" in your scenario. What happens after the limit is reached? It everything truncated after the limit? Provide more simple inputs and outputs to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @Neolisk I have added some screenshots to illustrate the outputs I want and the outputs that I am getting. Hopefully that helps clarify a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like....

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath)
Dim textLine As String
Dim count As Integer = MAIN_FORM.wordCountBox.Value
Dim pos As Integer = 0

Do While reader.Peek <> -1

    textLine = reader.ReadLine

    'Split the line to the individual words
    Dim parts = textLine.Split(" "c)
    Do
        'Add check to see if period is there
        Dim Periodfinder As Int32
        For Periodfinder = pos To parts.GetUpperBound(0)
            If parts(Periodfinder).ToString.Contains(".") Then Exit For
        Next
        'set periodfinder to difference between it and pos +1
        Periodfinder = Periodfinder - pos + 1
        'check if it is less than count
        If Periodfinder < count Then count = Periodfinder
        'Skip the previous words and take the count required
        Dim block = parts.Skip(pos).Take(count).ToArray

        'position to read the next count words
        pos += count
        'reset count
        count = MAIN_FORM.wordCountBox.Value

        If block.Count > 0 Then
            block(0) = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(block(0))
        End If

        MAIN_FORM.previewBox.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", block))
        'or if you dont want the period to be carried through
        MAIN_FORM.previewBox.Items.Add(String.Join(" ", block).Replace(".",""))

    Loop While (pos < parts.Length)

Loop
```

Code updated to allow for multiple periods in the string.

In the example in your comment below this turns One two three four five six seven eight nine ten into:

One two three four five six seven
Eight nine ten

and one two three. four five six seven. eight nine ten into:

One two three.
Four five six severn.
Eight nine ten

(if you set the limit to 7 words)

I am outputting to console.writeline to test it.

Example in Listbox control
[image]

In certain width/height ratios AND if the multicolumn is set to True then it will put the two entries side by side rather than one above the other!

Comment: That didn't work. I got the exception index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @slister added a check to overcome this.

Comment: that fixed the out of bounds error, but it still didn't accomplish my goal. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @slister If you can tell me where it fell short of your goal I will see if I can help, it appeared to do what I thought you wanted when I tested it here.

Comment: It didn't limit each line to one sentence. For example if I had a string of text like this "One two three four five six seven eight nine ten." It should end the line with the word seven and start the next line with eight nine ten because there were ten words which exceeds the threshold of 7; however, If there was a string like this "One two three. Four five six" It should end the line at three since there is a period there even though there are only three words. You see what I'm saying?

Comment: @slister Please see example above (wouldn't work when I tried to add line feeds to the comment)

Comment: yes that is what I want it to do. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @slister sorry I am still not 100% clear what you are after did my suggestion answer your Q OR in the case of one two three. four and so on do you not want the second line containing four five six?

Comment: Yes the second line would contain four five and six

Comment: @slister So does my answer NOT produce what you want? if so what is it not doing? when i tested it it produced the output at the bottom of the answer - is that what you wanted?

Comment: No it does not produce what I want. It only limits the lines to 7 words but it doesn't separate the sentences.

Comment: @slister can you update your Q with details as to what `previewbox` is and how it is configured?

Comment: Previewbox is just a simple listbox control, and what do you mean by how it's configured?

Comment: @slister i have added an image of what happens when i put the info into a listbox which is as i understand it exactly what you want, this means there MUST be something about your listbox set up that is causing it to display like it is - can you post an image of what you are getting when you try it?

Comment: I checked and multicolumn was set to false. I posted some screenshots explaining the output I am getting in my original post.

Comment: @slister sorry for the long delay, was returning from overseas and then had serious PC issues!! - I have updated the code to work with multiple periods, hope it is not too late to be of use to you!

Comment: No problem. I really appreciate how much effort you have put into this. The updated code does exactly what I want it to. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have one more addition. I would like it to remove the period from the string? How hard of a tweak would that be?

Comment: @slister - See update - probably other/better ways to do it but this works!